# Problem with database provider in ASP.NET NUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem and get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException : No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

This is my code:

```
public TestDbContext(Dictionary<Type, Type> customDependancyInjection = null, string customConfigurationJson = null)
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customConfigurationJson))
    {
        var customJsonStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(customConfigurationJson));
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonStream(customJsonStream);
    }

    var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
    services.AddScoped<ITokenAccessService, TokenAccessService>();
    services.AddScoped<IWebSocketService, WebSocketService>();
    services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher<User>>();

    var configurationDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IConfiguration));

    if (configurationDescriptor != null)
    {
        services.Remove(configurationDescriptor);
    }

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    var sqliteConn = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
    sqliteConn.CreateFunction("newid", () => Guid.NewGuid()); // potrzebne dla SQLite, bo nie zna metody "NEWID()"
    sqliteConn.Open();

    services.AddDbContext<LoginAppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlite(sqliteConn);
        _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(options.Options).Connection;
    });

    _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

My test:

```
    private TestDbContext testContext;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        passwordHasher = GetService<IPasswordHasher<User>>();
        accountService = GetService<AccountService>();
        testContext = new TestDbContext();
        CreateUser();
    }
```

My Visual Studio is screaming in line in which is declaration `_connection` that is null and when I debugged this line, it is null - but why? Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my English but I am already studying English and ASP.NET

Comment: I'm missing some details honestly. But you can follow this guide in order to write tests by mocking DbSets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking